# How to add Attendees to the existing recurrence meeting, but the for the new attendees the Recurrence should from the future date in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, meeting-request

I have an existing Recurrence meeting in Outlook from 1/10 to 30/11

Now i need to add new attendees from 07/11 on the same existing recurrence meeting

But for the new attendees the recurrence should get only from from 07/11.

How to do this in outlook 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a recurring series, they are all tied together. We cannot make changes only to future events.

You can cancel future occurrence and create a new recurring meeting.